# Google assistant triggers in hindi language

Tags: bluetooth, languages, bluetooth-audio, google-assistant

Whenever I trigger google assistant using bluetooth headphones, it starts speaks in hindi and I need to ask in hindi. But when I start assistant from mobile directly it works normally (in english).
How can I fix this to always work in english ?

Answer (score 0):

Could this problem be solved by going into keyboard settings and update the language feature? Android keyboard that came with the phone vs. app keyboards can vary greatly.Google assistant is in the input method of Android settings....it depends on your phone model but i would check there .hope it helps